# Root of the expectation of a random rational function

Tags: probability-distributions, rational-functions, expectation, zeroes

I am trying to figure out a formula for the unique $\lambda>1$ such that 
$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{X}{\lambda -X}\bigg]=1
$$
where $X$ is a discrete random variable taking values in $\{\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$, distributed w.r.t. some distribution $\mu$.

We can rewrite the expression above which yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\mu(\frac{k}{n})\frac{k}{n}}{\lambda-\frac{k}{n}} = 1.
$$

I know that there are no closed solutions for the roots of such a function, since they are based on solving for zeros of a high degree polynomial. Still, I think I miss some obvious results here how to analyse such a function.

I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thank's a lot!

Comment: Instead of writing $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\mu(\frac{k}{n})\frac{k}{n}}{x-\frac{k}{n}} = 1,$ why not write $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\mu(\frac{k}{n})\frac{k}{n}}{\lambda-\frac{k}{n}} = 1$ so that the notation is the same as in the expected $\vphantom{\displaystyle\int}$value that you wrote at the outset? $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited the post.